# Cross-platform hgrc solution?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm looking for a solution to have one .hgrc for mercurial to work in all my working environments(win/lin/mac), just like one vimrc to rule all.

It comes to a problem when I have to specify the path for some extensions, for example,  hg-git:

on windows:

```
[extensions]
hggit = E:\hg-git\hggit
```

on linux/mac:

```
[extensions]
hggit = ~/hg-git/hggit
```

For vimrc, we have solution to distinguish different platform, like

```
if has('win32')
  ...
endif
```

Knowing that mercurial's hgrc is barely a normal ini file, I wonder if there is similar solution for hgrc file.

Or maybe some other solution?

**Update**

Thanks for mentioning using "custom environment variable instead of hard coding", that works for extensions' path.

However, to make extensions work is just one goal. I believe there are other configurations' behavior that depends on platform, like in http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/OGREDeveloperGuide/index.html, specific options are needed for Windows and Mac. How to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Is there any chance that `$HOME/.hg-git/hggit` would work on all of them?

Comment: Thanks, and yes, that works for extensions. However, I think there are some more work for other options. See my update please.

Comment: Is having *only one* hgrc file a hard requirement? If not, you could use [commom and machine-specific hgrc files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1867237/151299). Personally I use this approach too .. works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the .hgrc include mechanism and three separate files:

```
~/.hgrc
~/.hgrc-windows
~/.hgrc-linux
```

where the main ~/.hgrc has:

```
%include .hgrc-$OS
```

and then set `$OS` in your windows profile and your linux profile's.  Alternately you could probably find an env variable that already exists on both systems ($USERNAME is usally already set in both windows and unix and may differ for you).

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought to use environment variable in this way, and you really open my mind. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, OS environment variable [is already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13124447/4600536) as "Windows_NT" on Windows platform

Answer (score 3):

This is just in case you don't find a way to have only one `.hgrc` (or one set of `.hgrc*` files, per Oben Sonne's comment).

I only face Windows environments, so my `mercurial.ini` files are the same except for 1 path. I keep a copy in version control along with my Powershell profile script.

However, if I were faced with environments more varied, I would abstract the configuration to a script in a cross-platform language (e.g., Python) that overwrites the target `.hgrc` or `mercurial.ini`. I'd be able to have the pieces that have to be different for each OS/machine right next each other with easy ways of distinguishing which environment is current. Then I would keep that script in version-control to help keep the same version on each machine.

Since I don't change it often, I would probably execute it manually on each machine when I visited it next. For a larger number of machines or more frequent changes, I would have another script executed on login that pulls changes to the generating script from a central repo, and if there were indeed new changes pulled, update to tip and run the script.

*(Heck, I'm now tempted to rig this kind of setup anyway.)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I definitely learned something. However, the solution seems to be administrator-oriented, which is more suitable for quite large number of computers for different users. It's little heavy relative to my need, IMO. So I pick another one as the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a custom environment variable instead of hard coding the paths?

Comment: Thanks. Using env. variable can solve problem for extensions. However, I think there are some more work for other options. Sorry to not mention them all at first. See my update please.